# Examples of basic German sentences containing lots of umlauts

Tags: umlaut, curiosity

Please provide examples of basic German sentences containing lots of umlauts.
For example: "Sie sind Ärzte und haben zwölf Bücher."

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: VTC because this doesn't really have a definitive answer and as such doesn't fit on SE.

Comment: That being said, would a single word suffice? "tränenüberströmt"

Comment: @infinitezero Und als Satz "Dörte hört völlig tränenüberströmt Mötörhead" - ups, ein ö zu viel

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking for a sentence to copy umlauts from? Here's one containing ÄÖÜäöüß:

```
Übeltäter übergibt Ärzten öfters äußerst ätzende Öle.
```

Comment: Bäuerliche Läden öffnen ihre Türen übermäßig häufig in ländlichen Häusern, für Äpfel und Öl aber drüben ;)

Comment: Übermüdete Ölförderer stellen Änderungsanträge.